# using a list which i am getting through messaging.inboundemailhandler and also wanted to use that list in future method as records are more than 10000

Tags: apex

```
global class FusionRefNoUpdate implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler {
   global static list<string> dunList = new list<string>();
       global static list<string> cusList = new list<string>();
       global static list<string> parList = new list<string>();
       global static list<string> saleList = new list<string>();
    global static list<string> dunList1 = new list<string>();
       global static list<string> cusList1 = new list<string>();
       global static list<string> parList1 = new list<string>();
       global static list<string> saleList1 = new list<string>();       
        global static list<SAP_Fusion_Custom__c> sapList2 = new list<SAP_Fusion_Custom__c>();
       global list<SAP_Fusion_Custom__c> sapList = new list<SAP_Fusion_Custom__c>();
       global list<SAP_Fusion_Custom__c> sapList3 = new list<SAP_Fusion_Custom__c>();
    
  
    global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.InboundEmail email, Messaging.InboundEnvelope envelope) {
        
        Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailresult();
        system.debug('email came');
        string fileAttachments='';
        string subToCompare = 'Update Sap Fusion Number';
        system.debug(+email.subject);
        if(email.subject.equalsIgnoreCase(subToCompare)){
            system.debug('It is under if');
            string fileAttchment = '';
            // Messaging.InboundEmail.TextAttachment[] tAttachments = email.textAttachments;
            // System.debug(' size of tAttachments ' + tAttachments.size() + 'Text Attachement from the email.' + tAttachments);
            Messaging.InboundEmail.BinaryAttachment[] bAttachments = email.BinaryAttachments;
            System.debug(' Binary Attachement from the email. ' + bAttachments);
            String csvbody = '';
            for(integer i=0; i < bAttachments.size(); i++)
            {
                System.debug(' attacments... ' + bAttachments[i]);
                fileAttachments = String.valueOf(bAttachments[i]);
            }system.debug('No of files:'+bAttachments.size());
            List<String> badrows = new List<String>();
            String csvBody1 = '';
            String[] lineByCsvBody = new String[]{};
                List<String> linebycsvdata = new List<String>();
            list<Account> accList2 = new list<account>();
            If(bAttachments != Null && bAttachments.size() > 0){
                For(Messaging.InboundEmail.binaryAttachment ttt : bAttachments)
                {
                    
                    csvBody1 = ttt.body.tostring();
                    //csvBody1 = EncodingUtil.Base64Encode(ttt.body);
                    lineByCsvBody = csvBody1.split('\n');
                    System.debug('CSV BODY'+ csvBody1 + 'lines' +lineByCsvBody +' size of lineByCsvBody ' + lineByCsvBody.size() + ' This is a Binary Attachment from the email parsed. ' + ttt);
                    For(Integer j = 0; j < lineByCsvBody.size(); j++){
                        System.debug(' lineByCsvBody data...... ' + lineByCsvBody[j]); 
                        If(j==0)
                        { 
                            // Here I'm checking and splitting the header values //
                            String headerRow = lineByCsvBody[j];
                            System.debug(' headerRow DATA ...  ' + headerRow);
                            String hvalue = csvBody1;
                            String[] headervalue = headerRow.split(',');
                            System.debug(' size of headervalue ' + headervalue.size());
                            // System.debug(' headervalue1 '+ headervalue[0] + ' headervalue2 ' + headervalue[1]
                            //           + ' headervalue3 ' + headervalue[2] + ' headervalue3 ' + headervalue[4]);
                        }
                        if(j>0){
                            system.debug('Before linebycsvdata add ');
                            linebycsvdata.add(lineByCsvBody[j]);
                            system.debug('Inside j>0'+linebycsvdata);
                        }                                                
                    }
                    
                    
                    integer rowcount=0;
                    for(String svalue:linebycsvdata){
                        //Here I'm checking and splitting the values / data contained in the .csv file
                        rowCount++;
                        String[] splitvalue = svalue.split(',');
                       // System.debug(' size of splitvalue ' + splitvalue.size());
                        dunList.add(splitvalue[0]);
                        cusList.add(splitvalue[1]);
                        parList.add(splitvalue[2]);
                        saleList.add(splitvalue[3]);
                    }system.debug('duns no are:'+dunList);
                    integer dunSize=dunList.size();
                    
                    
        
                    if(dunSize > 0){
                        
                        for(integer a=0;a<9999;a++){
                            SAP_Fusion_Custom__c sap = new SAP_Fusion_Custom__c();  
                            sap.Name = dunList.get(a);
                            sap.Customer__c = cusList.get(a);
                            sap.Partner__c = parList.get(a);
                            sap.Sales_org__c = saleList.get(a);
                            sapList.add(sap);
                            
                        }//insert sapList;
                        system.debug('sapListsize'+sapList.size());  
                         
                       /*  for(integer a=9999;a<19998;a++){
                             string dun;
                        string customer;
                        string partner;
                        string sale;
                            dun = dunList.get(a);
                            customer = cusList.get(a);
                            partner = parList.get(a);
                            sale = saleList.get(a);
                            dunList1.add(dun);
                            cusList1.add(customer);
                            parList1.add(partner);
                            saleList1.add(sale);
                        }system.debug(+dunList1);
                        system.debug('size of 2nd List '+dunList1.size());*/
                        
                    
                        
                        firstmethod();
                        
                      
                    }
                    
                                      
                }
            }
            
        }
        
        
        return result;
        
        
       
    }
    @future
        global static void firstmethod(){
            
            
            system.debug('Future method');
            system.debug('dunList size'+dunList.size());
            for(integer b=9999;b<18997;b++){
                system.debug('size of 2nd dun List'+dunList1);
                            SAP_Fusion_Custom__c sap1 = new SAP_Fusion_Custom__c();  
                            
                            sap1.Name = dunList.get(b);
                            sap1.Customer__c = cusList.get(b);
                            sap1.Partner__c = parList.get(b);
                            sap1.Sales_org__c = saleList.get(b);
                            sapList2.add(sap1);
                            
                        }system.debug('size of sapList2'+sapList2.size());
            
                    //insert sapList2;
            
        }
    


}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please make sure to include only the *relevant portions* of your code, along with the *specific issue* you are struggling with and the complete text and location of any errors, in the body of your question. See [ask] for more about our expectations, and please [edit] your question to add information rather than posting comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem you're having is that you expect all those global variable to hold the data from your handleInboundEmail to still exist in your future method. It won't.

The future method is a separate transaction that will not remember anything you did before. You need to pass in that data in order for it to be processed. Even worse, this code assumes there are 20,000 rows, but there may not be.

Your boundary conditions are also incorrect, you're only actually handling 9999 records, not 10000 (0-9998 is 9999 total). Also, it presumes there won't be more than 20,000 rows (well, 18998 records), so you may lose data anyways.

You're also making assumptions about the type of data from the CSV, it's not a "real" CSV file, which may cause problems in some situations.

Overall, you probably need to go back to the drawing board and start over.

First, I suggest that you start with a decent CSV parser, such as the ones I list in [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/276606/2984).

Second, you're using complicated data types, so you should probably look at a [Queueable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_queueing_jobs.htm) instead of a future method. This way, you can process 10,000 rows of DML indefinitely until they're all processed.

Third, you should optimize your code for at least moderate performance. Methods like `String.equalsIgnoreCase` can be simply `==` (see how much easier that is to read?), `List.get(x)` can be replaced with simply `[x]`,

Fourth, construct the records directly. There's no actual reason you need to parse them into lists, and then construct the records. It's taking up a lot of CPU time and bloating your code. You can split the DML lists into bundles of 10000, like this:

```
List<List<SAP_Fusion_Custom__c>> bundles = new List<List<SAP_Fusion_Custom__c>>();
List<SAP_Fusion_Custom__c> bundle = new List<SAP_Fusion_Custom__c>();
for(String svalue:linebycsvdata) {
    String[] splitvalue = svalue.split(',');
    bundle.add(
        new SAP_Fusion_Custom__c(
            Name = splitvalue[0],
            Customer__c = splitvalue[1],
            Partner__c = splitvalue[2],
            Sales_org__c = splitvalue[3]
        )
    );
    if(bundle.size() == 10000) {
        bundles.add(bundle);
        bundle = new List<SAP_Fusion_Custom__c>();
    }
}
if(bundle.size() > 0) {
    bundles.add(bundle);
}
Database.insert(bundles.remove(0), false);
if(bundles.size() > 0) {
    System.enqueueJob(
        new BulkDataSapFusionCustomInsert(bundles)
    );
}
```

The job itself just handles each one in a row:

```
public class BulkDataSapFusionCustomInsert implements Queueable {
    List<List<SAP_Fusion_Custom__c>> bundles;
    public BulkDataSapFusionCustomInsert(List<List<SAP_Fusion_Custom__c>> bundles) {
        this.bundles = bundles;
    }
    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
        Database.insert(bundles.remove(0));
        if(bundles.size() > 0) {
            System.enqueueJob(this); // Do again while more
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, this can handle as many records as you can fit in memory.

In summary, you have a lot of work ahead of you to fix the many problems you have ahead of you, but it can be done.